# mapping kernel config variables to modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In general, how do I know what set of kernel config options are necessary to have some .ko file built?

For example, I need 'xt_conntrack.ko'. What resources are there that let me know whether or not enabling `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=m` in my kernel config is necessary or even sufficient to result in my built .ko file? How do I find the full set of kconfig options required to yield a kernel module?

http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK.html indicates it will build "xt_conntrack", but I am not seeing it when I `=m` it and all of its dependencies.
On the other side, there is no set of kconfig flags visible here (http://modules.libres.ch/browse/linux/v3.0/x86_64/xt_conntrack/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I find the full set of kconfig options required to yield a kernel module?

In general, determining set of options for building a kernel module is complex process. Steps described below may guide in that process.

## 1. Find a *Makefile*

Find a `Makefile` which builds a kernel module. This file is located in the same  directory, where `.ko` file is produced; this directory usually coincides with a directory of module's source files. This `Makefile` contains a line which builds a module:

```
obj-${CONFIG_...} := <module_name>.o
```

**Example**:

A module `xt_conntrack.ko` is built by the line

```
obj-$(CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK) += xt_conntrack.o
```

in file `net/netfilter/Makefile`.

## 2. Determine final *option*

There are several ways how configuration options may affect on building a module.

1. The option is used directly in the line, produced the module:

   ```
   obj-${CONFIG_X} := <module_name>.o
   ```

   means that option `CONFIG_X` should be set for the module to be built.
2. Given `Makefile` is *conditionally* included into the *upper* one:

   ```
   obj-${CONFIG_Y} := <dir>/
   ```
3. The line produced the module is guarded by "if" clause:

   ```
   ifeq ($(CONFIG_F),y)
   obj-m := <module_name>.o
   endif
   ```

   Alternatively, guard may protect inclusion of the `Makefile` from the *upper* one:

   ```
   ifeq ($(CONFIG_F),y)
   obj-m := <dir>/
   endif
   ```

**Example**:

A module `xt_conntrack` depends by rule 1 from `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK` option.

Also it depends by rule 2 from `CONFIG_NETFILTER` option, because outer `net/Makefile` includes `net/netfilter/Makefile` via

```
obj-$(CONFIG_NETFILTER) += netfilter/
```

## 3. Find *definition* of the option and determine its *availability*

**Note:** This is the most complicated step, mainly because availability of the option is expressed in terms of *other options*. It is recommended to use ready-made tools for that. E.g., `make menuconfig` tool may search options and show their definition.

Every configuration option is *defined* in one of `Kconfig` files.

Definition determines:

- availability of the option (when the option can be used),
- possible values of the option (`y`/`n` - boolean, `y`/`m`/`n` - tristate, etc.),
- whether the option can be set by a user.

**Example**:

Option `NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK` is defined in `net/netfilter/Kconfig` as

```
config NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK
    tristate '"conntrack" connection tracking match support'
    depends on NF_CONNTRACK
    default m if NETFILTER_ADVANCED=n
    help
      This is a general conntrack match module, a superset of the state match.

      It allows matching on additional conntrack information, which is
      useful in complex configurations, such as NAT gateways with multiple
      internet links or tunnels.

      To compile it as a module, choose M here.  If unsure, say N.
```

That is, the option is available (can be set) only when `NF_CONNTRACK` option is set.

Documentation for format of `Kconfig` files is located at [Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt).

Comment: Browsing symbols in *make nconfig* makes things easier to get, though it requires manual work to be done.